# What does it mean to play in an 'arpeggiated' style on the guitar?

Tags: guitar, terminology, arpeggios

I sometimes hear a guitar player described as having an 'arpeggiated' style, such as Peter Buck of R.E.M.

I know that an arpeggio is the 1st, 3rd, 5th and 8th of a scale, but exactly what does it mean to play this style on the guitar?

Comment: Note, that an arpeggio is not always the 1st, 3rd and 5th; it's a decomposition of the chord, so e.g. for a Dsus4, it's the 1st, 4th and 5th.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An arpeggio is simply a chord played one note at a time.  So if you're playing in an arpeggiated style, then instead of strumming the chords, you'll play each note of the chord one at a time.  You mention Peter Buck, whose playing on "[Everybody Hurts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijZRCIrTgQc)" is a perfect example of arpeggiated playing.

Strumming a D-chord:

```
$D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 | $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 | $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 | $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 $D.0.$G.2.$B.3.$e.2 ||
```

Arpeggiating a D-chord:

```
$D 0 $G 2 $B 3 | $e 2 $B 3 $G 2 | $D 0 $G 2 $B 3 | $e 2 $B 3 $G 2 ||
```